# How to style rails time_select field?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, time-select

I want to add bootstrap form-control class to rails time_select control. I try this but it doesnt work.

```
 <%= time_select :open_time, :prompt , :default => {:hour => '9', :minute => '30'} ,  class: "form-control" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar challenge of styling `time_select` with Bootstrap and after reading through the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_time) I was able to have them work.

I noticed that when using the `form_helpers` there is somewhat a different way of working with the `time_select` and below are the examples;

### Using `time_select` without `form_helper`

The syntax is `time_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})` and it can be seen that HTML options is the 4th parameter so applying Bootstrap class(es) can only work when passed to the fourth parameter.

In this case, the actual implementation can be as below;

```
<%= time_select("my_object", "my_method", {include_seconds: true, prompt: { hour: 'Choose hour', minute: 'Choose minute', second: 'Choose seconds' } }, {class: "form-control"} ) %>
```

It can clearly be seen that I used the curly braces `**{}**` to **group** the various options together, if not, the HTML options will not render and will even throw an error because in this case your parameters passed are more than required of the method. An example is a code below;

#### Attemp 1

```
<%= time_select("my_object", "my_method", include_seconds: true,
    prompt: { hour: 'Choose hour', minute: 'Choose minute', second: 'Choose seconds' }, 
    class: "form-control" ) %>
```

*Attempt 1 will not render the HTML options because the `time_select` method accepts only four parameters but we have passed five to it.*

#### Attempt 2

```
<%= time_select("my_object", "my_method",
    prompt: { hour: 'Choose hour', minute: 'Choose minute', second: 'Choose seconds' }, 
    class: "form-control" ) %>
```

*Attempt 2 will still not render the HTML options though the number of parameters passed is up to four as required by the `time_select` method because I have failed to group the 3rd and 4th parameters*

#### Attempt 3

```
<%= time_select("my_object", "my_method", 
    { prompt: { hour: 'Choose hour', minute: 'Choose minute', second: 'Choose seconds' } }, 
    {class: "form-control" } ) %>
```

*Attempt 3 will render the HTML options passed to the method. In trying several options of grouping the 3rd and 4th parameters, I noticed that grouping them with the `**{}**` is important and the only way to avoid errors and non-rendering of HTML options.*

### Using `time_select` with `form_helper`

I noticed that sometimes we are mistaken to differentiate between the two (when using `time_select` with and without `form_helper`.

Below is the syntax of the `time_select` method if used with a `form_helper` as indicated [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.0/classes/ActionView/FormBuilder.html#method-i-time_select) in the documentation;

```
time_select(method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

It can be seen that amongst the two ( `time_select(object, method, options = {}, html_options = {} )` and `time_select(method, option = {}, html_options = {}`) are not the same in terms of parameters to be passed to them.

The code block below is how I implemented it with a `form_helper`;

```
<%= form.time_select :duration, {include_seconds: true, 
    prompt: { hour: 'Choose hour', minute: 'Choose minute', second: 'Choose seconds' }}, 
    {class: "form-control"} %>
```

### Why I Answered

I tried answering this with explanations so we can clearly see the differences; because I first used the `time_select` with a `form_helper`, applied HTML options and it worked but I decided to read more about the `time_select` method and I started noticing the differences hence my reason to share this piece.

## Important

I realized that grouping the ***options*** in the method with `*{}*` is necessary for the two to render HTML options.

I hope it serves a purpose!

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-time_select) state: `time_select(method, options = {}, html_options = {})`

So in your case: `<%= time_select :open_time, { prompt: {hour: '9', minute: '30'} }, { class: 'form-control' } %>`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesnt looks like bootstrap select. https://yadi.sk/i/1JALnRMy3GLKCF I will use 2 textbox for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `time_select` method of rails.

```
def time_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})
  Tags::TimeSelect.new(object_name, method, self, options, html_options).render
end
```

So, from the above method you can use `html_options` for adding the `html` attributes.

So, your code becomes,

```
 <%= time_select :open_time, :prompt , :default => {:hour => '9', :minute => '30'} ,  html_options: {class: "form-control"} %>
```

[Here is the **reference**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_select)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesnt looks like bootstrap select. https://yadi.sk/i/1JALnRMy3GLKCF I will use 2 textbox for this.

Comment: you should have bootstrap in your project and make sure it is working, and inspect and check if the select tag is coming